# Inconsistency of accuracy between tensorflow version

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'am the newbie on keras/tensorflow.

Between the another version of keras, tensorflow, there was inconsistency the result in terms of accuracy.

I don't know why.

Thank you in advance!

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

'1.15.2'

```
from tensorflow import keras
keras.__version__
```

'2.2.4-tf'

```
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import InputLayer, Dense, BatchNormalization, Activation, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import regularizers

classify = [
    InputLayer(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    
    Dense(128),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),

    Dense(64, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-5)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Activation('relu'),
    
    Dense(1),
    Activation('sigmoid')
]

model = Sequential(classify)
```

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=128, shuffle="batch")
print(model.metrics_names, model.evaluate(X_test, y_test))
```

['loss', 'acc'] [0.02403441002866048, 0.994511238891793]

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

'2.3.0'

```
from tensorflow import keras
keras.__version__
```

'2.4.0'

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=128, shuffle="batch")
print(model.metrics_names, model.evaluate(X_test, y_test))
```

['loss', 'accuracy'] [0.6886715888977051, 0.5517511963844299]

Comment: ```
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

When I added this code, I got the same result.
How can I inspect the difference of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i, var in enumerate(model.trainable_weights):
    print(model.trainable_weights[i].name)
```

ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40638

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.executing_eagerly()
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.executing_eagerly()
```

This problem cuase by [Eager](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) in tensorflow 2